# About python's round function

Tags: python

I feel confused about python's round function ,

```
round(1.835,2)
->1.83
round(1.8351,2)
->1.84
```

I expect round(1.835,2) is 1.84. 
What know/how I miss ?

Comment: @bernie That's not the reason.

Comment: @Barmar: oh please do educate me! :-)

Comment: @bernie As that question says, Python normally rounds at the halfway point to even. But in that case, he would get his expected result. The reason it's not is because `.835` can't be represented exactly in floating point, so it's not really at the halfway point. The representation is slightly below `.835`, so it rounds down.

Comment: @Barmar thank you very much for the information! :-)